# How to remove object after comparing to remaining objects in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, compare, lifecycle, unit-of-work

I've been asking the same question in different versions for the last two days but never got an answer, so I hope maybe now someone can help me or rather, I ask it more accurately :)

Just very simple: I create a document --> gets assigned to an agency --> belongs to a market.

There are 3 markets and 100 of entities, so for my documents, I display each agency but only distinct markets so I don't have any duplicates.

Next to adding agencies & markets, I want to be able to remove them again. So what could happen is:

I remove an agency from the "US"-market and there is no other agency from that market left so as a consequence, the US-market should be removed as well.
And that's where I'm stuck.

How can I check whether the market of the to-be-removed agency is still under the remaining markets or not? And then how can it be removed?

Here's what I tried:

```
PostUpdate function with UnitOfWork -> getEntityChangeSet()
PreUpdate function with UnitOfWork -> getNew - and OldValue()
OnFlush functino with UnitOfWork -> getScheduledEntityUpdates()
```

Btw: markets and agencies have a manytomany relationship to my document, and are constructed as arraycollections, so I have the remove/add functions for both of them!

Comment: Hi sonja. Can you post your code on github or pastebin so we can take a look. It's better to post there rather then here because the large number of lines. You just need to provide the links. In particular we need to see your controller code, and where the error is occuring.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post the project. But I would be happy to provide the specific lines you need in order to help me :)
I think my biggest problem is, that I don't know what functions exist or how they work to achieve what I would like to..

Comment: If you expect help you'll need to post something. Can you obsfucate the code?

Comment: I'd be happy to post the code here, it's not really that long  :)
just let me know what you need! :)

Comment: I would be surprised if it's not very long, but how about the controller code?

Comment: @AlvinBunk: you seem to be giving advice contrary to Stack Overflow guidelines. Broadly, posts must be self-contained here, though material may be repeated on external sites (e.g. Fiddles) if they are also shown here. If a question's material is exclusively off-site then (a) it is prone to link breakage, and (b) it forces readers to click off-site links, and (c) it is off-topic.

Comment: Sonja: would you indicate, by links in the comments, which prior questions are duplicates of this? I'd ask that you don't do that in the future, since it creates clean-up work for volunteers. I will see if I can get the old questions closed, so any answers there will be redirected here. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer I'm very familiar with SO guidlines, I'm also familiar with the OP, and have seen her previous posts. She's a new user, and she appears to be new to Symfony as well. She may not know how to show minimal code to post in her question, and that's why I was asking to post externally --> so I can look at all of the code and figure out where it's going wrong. And then after possibly editing her post to show the problem code. Thanks for reviewing the questions though. Your efforts are appreciated!

Comment: Cheers @Alvin! IMO, it's worth being careful how posting advice is offered here, since while you're obviously aware of the guidelines, a consumer of your advice may not be. Thanks for wanting to go the extra mile for the OP though.

Comment: Do you still need help sonja?

Comment: Thanks @AlvinBunk and @halfer! I was off the last day so I didn't reply. 
It's definitely true, I'm new to both, Stackoverflow and Symfony/programming so I bet some of my questions must appear really stupid.
Anyway, I figured a way out how to remove the objects. Even though I'm not sure whether it's the most efficient way to do it.
I will add an answer with the code inside but if you see anything I could improve, please let me know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to solve my problem:

In my document entity I have a prePersist function (the one, where I also added the markets.

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
* @ORM\PreFlush
*/
public function prePersist() {

    $markets = $this->getMarkets();

    if(count($this->getMarkets())>0){
      foreach($this->getMarkets() as $market) {
          $this->removeMarket($market);
      }
    }

    if(count($this->getAgencies()) > 0){
      foreach($this->getAgencies() as $agency) {
        if(!$this->markets->contains($agency->getMarket())) {
          $this->addMarket($agency->getMarket());
        }
      }
    }
}
```

So I kind of remove all the markets and then run through the foreach loop for distinctly adding all of them again. I bet there is a more efficiently way to do that but it works for me so far :)

Comment: Does `$this->getMarkets();` return and `ArrayCollection`?

Comment: @AlvinBunk yes it does :)

Answer (score 1):

This code is simpler:

```
$markets = $this->getMarkets();
$markets->clear();
```

You can read [the API Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html). I think it should work. Also your above can be simplified as well if this doesn't work. And since my solution is only 2 lines of code, you can probably just put in your controller.

Comment: thank you! I figured there must be a simpler solution!